# Certification of Aircraft Phone/Tablet Mounts/Holders

Tags: aircraft-design, faa, easa-regulations, faa-approval

I would like to know, whether it is required for such items to be certified for application on genaral and/or commercial aircraft:

https://www.rammount.com/part/RAM-B-166-MP1U

https://mgfproducts.com/products/sport-mount-flex-suction?variant=10434660040819

In what countries is it necessary?
Is it compulsory or not for them to be certified?

I would be gratuful for any help!)

Answer (score 4):

For general aviation no certification is required, neither is certification required for at least some commercial operations like flight training, at least for the regulatory bodies I'm familiar with (FAA and EASA). I've seen Ram and Garmin mounts being used on some smaller passenger and cargo operations as well, usually GPS and tablets in older prop airplanes like the DC3, Beechcraft twins and the like.

As for carrier airline operations I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

For items like that are that not permanently attached, certification on the aircraft itself is not an issue because from the airplane's perspective, the item doesn't exist (it would be no different than attaching a pen to something with chewing gum or scotch tape).

However, a local authority may have a regulation against temporarily attached devices for whatever reason, or a manufacturer may have a restrictive policy that affects warranty (like say, a manufacturer may have a policy that says suction cup devices void warranty on new aircraft windshields or windows to which they are attached).